# Laravel - migrations doesn't work after manual removal of tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I have created 2 migrations in order to create 2 tables in Laravel, but I manually deleted these tables from database. Now, when I want to re-create these tables with migration, none of the following artisan commands works:

```
artisan migrate, artisan migrate:install, artisan migrate:refresh, artisan migrate:reset
```

It will return error like "nothing to migrate" or "tables [name] already exists" etc. I think laravel is somewhere keeping record of created tables. But how can I fix it now?

Comment: You have to delete rows about these two migrations form migrations table

Comment: where can i find that table exactly?

Comment: I suggest never to do any manual changes on the database when using migrations. Every time I did (because I just wanted quickly ...) it was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

At first Manually delete all the Tables of your database also the migrations table, make your current database empty and then migrate the database and now you can use any artisan command for migration